# shifting column in pandas without eliminating data

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Input:

```
##      x2
##0    214
##1    234
##2    253
##3    272
##4    291
```

Desired output:

```
##     x2
##0    291
##1    214
##2    234
##3    253
##4    272
```

Following code eliminates bottom part of the shifted column and puts NA on top. However, I want it as a cycle.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([214,234,253,272,291], columns=['x2'])
a.x2 = a.x2.shift(1)
```

Comment: do us a favor an add some code we can copy/paste to make a dataframe.

Comment: @PaulH : I have edited the way you have asked. Let me know if there is anything I should add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just chain a call to fill `fillna` after the call to `shift`:

```
import pandas
a = pandas.DataFrame([214,234,253,272,291], columns=['x2'])
a['x3'] = a.shift(1).fillna(a['x2'].iloc[-1])
print(a)

   x2   x3
0  214  291
1  234  214
2  253  234
3  272  253
4  291  272
```

You can reassign directly to the `x2` column, but I wanted to be able to show both the source and the result a once for comparison

Comment: Thanks for answer!